# Laravel Gate and Policy call order

Tags: laravel, permissions, policy

I'm working on a Laravel 5.7 site, trying to implement some new gates and policies on a site that has a few arbitrarily defined already.  I am having issues figuring our the order in which gates and policies are discovered and employed when @can($name, $class) is called.  The Laravel Authorization help page https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authorization says

> The before method of a policy class will not be called if the class doesn't contain a method with a name matching the name of the ability being checked.

and

> If a policy is registered for the given model, the can method will automatically call the appropriate policy and return the Boolean result. If no policy is registered for the model, the can method will attempt to call the Closure based Gate matching the given action name.

So when @can($name, $class) is used, it seems like Laravel will:

1. Find a matching policy class via policy-model registrations and the Class of $class.
2. If none are found, skip to #10
3. Search for a matching policy functions, specified by $name.
4. If none are found, skip to #10
5. If there's a policy before() function, run it.
6. Run the policy function found via steps 1 and 3.
7. (Is there a policy after() function?)
8. If there's a Gate::before() function (even if a match is not found in step 10,) run it.
9. Attempt to find a matching Gate::define() or Gate::resource() function and run it.
10. If there's a Gate::after() function (even if a match is not found in step 10,) run it.

Questions:

- Is this correct?  Did I miss anything?
- Do the other auth functions work differently?  If so, how?

  1. Gate::allow()
  2. Gate::denies
  3. $user->can()
  4. middleware('can:...')
  5. $this->authorize()
  6. $this->authorizeResource()
  7. @cannot()
- Is there an after() function capability in the policy classes?
- How does Laravel find a matching gate in step 10?
- Is Laravel able to find a gate match based on the $class Class?
- Does the gate need an exact $name match?
- Can it figure out 'noun-verb' Gate names, and pick one based on the Class of $class?

Just a note: It seems (though not specifically stated in the documentation, yet alluded to) that the policy functions have the ability to determine the class of the object passed to it, but the gate functions don't.  This may be why gates appear to have a 'verb-noun' name format like 'update-post' and policies appear to have a 'verb' name format (like 'update')

=== Update,

I'm seeing evidence that Gate::before() is run first, before the policies, in any situation.

Comment: When this type of things happens, the only way to truly know is just by going to the source code... So, [can](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/b9203fca96960ef9cd8860cb4ec99d1279353a8d/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/Access/Authorizable.php#L16-L19) goes here, and that goes [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/57c5672e12a9bcb6143134dc5644a2b45fe9d207/src/Illuminate/Auth/Access/Gate.php#L340-L345).

Comment: You can see that [these 2](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/57c5672e12a9bcb6143134dc5644a2b45fe9d207/src/Illuminate/Auth/Access/Gate.php#L392-L441) are the responsible ones for giving back an answer